# change image src using selenium webdriver

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium, src

I have a project in where I want to upload image to image tag in web page using upload box , I can do that by selenium web driver by opening the upload box then writing the image path then pressing open .I tried to ignore the upload box by changing the image attribute "src" but I could not do that. I tried the following code but it does not make any changes.

```
                        String script = "document.getElementById('img1').src='" + "C:\\Uploading files\\276090223\\276090223.jpg" + "';";

                        ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript(script);
```

how can I change the image src attribute  which takes its value from javascript method?

Comment: Does any one have  a solution or even a hint?

Comment: Also, this is not typically how you upload files in Selenium. You need to find a (usually hidden) `input` tag with `type='file'`, then after you locate it do something like `Element.SendKeys("absolute path to file");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the `'img1'` ID is unique, I'd try

```
IWebElement Element = driver.FindElement(By.Id("img1"));
((IJavaScriptExecutor) driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('src', 'C:\\Uploading files\\276090223\\276090223.jpg');", Element);
```

Comment: I tried this code  and it does not make any changes but when I tried to change another attribute inside the same tag (like name attribute ) it changed successfully. what is the problem in src attribute

Comment: Doesn't change the DOM you mean? Can you show us this part of the DOM and what surrounds it?

Comment: Src attribute takes the image path from uploading box but I need to ignore this uploading box and send the path directly to that "src" attribute

Comment: Per my comment above, can you search the page for `input` tag with `type='file'`?

Comment: Here when I tried to change src attribute ....."<img id="img1" name="img1" 
src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABgAAAAYCAYAAADgdz34AAAABmJLR0QA/wD/AP+gvaeTAAAAtElEQVRIie3UMQ4BQRTG8V+2IkoX0LuAC0gcw1GUOkdwAXEJodK6ALVOKWhWzFordo3sFv7JK968yfdNZuY9/jSJEQ64fhn7VCvHPoJ4aJLjXvyWjE4SQfAtnxqssfqlwUWE62vUG3SxRKeyc8DgKW9jk+6dl9B5WRjijGmaJ1jI/vlxVYMejsH6BDP5pjqhX9aghe0LsaLYebxHqSuqQn2dfHg6QdUItTKMxJmoheP6Tz3cAD0lh4vyKjH6AAAAAElFTkSuQmCC" 
onclick="viewImage(this)" class="clickable">"

Comment: when I tried to change "name " attribute it changed successfully ......."
<img id="img1" name="C:Uploading filesS456S456789.jpg" 
src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABgAAAAYCAYAAADgdz34AAAABmJLR0QA/wD/AP+gvaeTAAAAtElEQVRIie3UMQ4BQRTG8V+2IkoX0LuAC0gcw1GUOkdwAXEJodK6ALVOKWhWzFordo3sFv7JK968yfdNZuY9/jSJEQ64fhn7VCvHPoJ4aJLjXvyWjE4SQfAtnxqssfqlwUWE62vUG3SxRKeyc8DgKW9jk+6dl9B5WRjijGmaJ1jI/vlxVYMejsH6BDP5pjqhX9aghe0LsaLYebxHqSuqQn2dfHg6QdUItTKMxJmoheP6Tz3cAD0lh4vyKjH6AAAAAElFTkSuQmCC"
 onclick="viewImage(this)" class="clickable">"

Comment: "Per my comment above, can you search the page for input tag with type='file'?"   I can't understand this comment

Comment: Look on the page for anything that matches the CSS Selector `'input[type="file"]'`

Comment: do you mean that tag  .. ..... <input id="upload1input" name="upload1input" type="file" onchange="uploadImage(1, this)" class="hidden">

Comment: If that is what you mean.what is the next step?